# Principal component analysis - graph of individuals

Tags: r, pca

I would like to know if it is possible to show only selected groups on the chart, or to make some graphs of individuals, because in my PCA I have more than 10 groups and are not legible on the one chart. I will present my problem on iris data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(factoextra)
data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)
fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, label="none", habillage=iris$Species)
```

So, for example, can I show only a collection of setos on the graph? Or only setosa and versicolor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fviz_pca_ind` supports subset of data with `select.ind` parameter:

> ```
> select.ind
> a selection of individuals/variables to be drawn. Allowed values are NULL or a list containing the arguments name, cos2 or contrib:
>
> name: is a character vector containing individuals/variables to be drawn
> cos2: if cos2 is in [0, 1], ex: 0.6, then individuals/variables with a cos2 > 0.6 are drawn. if cos2 > 1, ex: 5, then the top 5 individuals/variables with the highest cos2 are drawn.
> contrib: if contrib > 1, ex: 5, then the top 5 individuals/variables with the highest cos2 are drawn
> ```

It's not possible to directly specify `setosa`, but you can specify indices of `setosa` rows.

```
setosa_indices <- rownames(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",])

fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, label = "none",
             habillage = iris$Species,
             select.ind = list(name = setosa_indices))
```

And the result:

[image: PCA analysis only for <code>setosa</code>]